# What do I do when a user deliberately asks a duplicate that is not answered

Tags: discussion, support, flags, duplicate-questions

I while ago, I saw 1 legitimate question, that did not have an answer yet, and another question (not by the same user), which looks something like:

> I have the same problem as *link*.

followed by a brief explanation of the question that was linked.

Naturally, I would flag such question, but that duplicate question does not have any answer.

Should I flag the post, or is this tolerated?

Comment: If the dupe didn't have any answers, this could be very ironic. :) (though you didn't do it on purpose :))

Comment: @ShadowWizard It's got 2 good answers. Irony has been escaped

Answer (score 1):

If it is the exact same question indeed, then this is definitely *not* tolerated at all.

In this case you can just flag it for moderator attention using a custom reason and explain the situation (preferably with a link to the original question if not already there). They can always close questions as duplicates of unanswered ones, or handle the situation in any other way they deem fit. It's certainly something that's worth making them aware of if the community can't handle it appropriately.